# How retrieve the content of the last page opened with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

The call to `this.getPageContent()` doesn't retrieve the content of the last page opened.

How retrieve the content of the **last** page opened ?

```js
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    waitTimeout: 10000,
    retryTimeout: 1000
});


casper.start(function() {
    this.open('http://example.com/contentTypes', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    });
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.then(function() {
    // get content of http://example.com/contentTypes << OK
    var ressources_type = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
    require('utils').dump(ressources_type);

    for (var i in ressources_type.data) {
        this.thenOpen('http://example.com/ressource?type=' + ressources_type['data'][i]['key'] , {
            method: 'get',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        });

        // get content of http://example.com/contentTypes instead of http://example.com/ressource?type=' + ressources_type['data'][i]['key']
        var ressources = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
        require('utils').dump(ressources);

        for (var j in ressources['data']) {
            ...
        }

    }
});


casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Comment: *Unrelated:* Are you sure you want such a long `retryTimeout`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. unfortunately, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is asynchronous in nature. Every `then*` and `wait*` call (step functions) schedules the passed function, but doesn't execute it immediately. You are mixing asynchronous calls (`thenOpen`) with synchronous calls (`getPageContent`).

You need to move every synchronous call into a step function.

```
this.thenOpen('http://example.com/ressource?type=' + ressources_type['data'][i]['key'] , {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json'}
});
this.then(function(){
    var ressources = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
    require('utils').dump(ressources);

    for (var j in ressources['data']) {
        ...
    }
});
```